# Создания методов с хеша Ruby

Tags: ruby, методы

У меня есть некий хеш, предположим `hash = { one: 'first', two: 'second' }` необходимо через initializer в классе создавать методы с названием как ключ хеша, и в теле метода будет puts который выводит значения хеша, вот так:

```
def one
  puts 'first'
end
```

Вот что я пробовал сделать:

```
class MetaProgramming
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      define_method(:key) { puts "#{value}" }
    end
  end
end
hash = { one: 'first', two: 'second' }
a = MetaProgramming.new(hash)
puts a.one
```

но получаю ошибку:

```
undefined method `define_method' for #<MetaProgramming:0x0055dd0d041088>
Did you mean?  define_singleton_method
```

Через синглтон тоже не работает:

```
undefined method `one' for #<MetaProgramming:0x0056413d017b90>
```

Подскажите, где я допускаю ошибку

Comment: Я даже не знаю, стоит ли отвечать на вопрос полноценно или ограничиться комментарием, потому что ошибка дубовая (не в обиду вам, случается с лучшими из  нас): вы раз за разом определяете метод `key`, потому что используете символ `:key`, а не переменную `key` (содержащую интересующий вас символ).

Comment: @D-side спасибо, тут свою ошибку понял, но кроме этого нашел еще одну и смог решить проблему в целом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался:

```
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      self.class.send :define_method, key do value end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Есть, правда, неприятность: методы всех инстансов этого класса полетят в сам класс, общий для них всех. Использовать синглтонный вариант может быть предпочтительнее.

Comment: @D-side я правильно понимаю, что если сделать так: `define_singleton_method(key) { puts "#{value}" }` тогда эти методы допишутся только инстансу класса?

Comment: Да. Почти. Тонкость в том, что методы ищутся у класса. И этим способом вы дописываете методы в "singleton class" (я предпочитаю термин "метакласс") этого конкретного инстанса. Других инстансов этого класса нет, и создать их нельзя, так что добавленных таким способом методов больше ни у кого не возникнет.